# how do I set an id column in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am able to set a id column in my table, using this sql code in phpmyadmin:

```
SET @i = 0;
UPDATE albums SET id=(@i:=@i+1);
```

this wil give each row in the id column a consecutive number.
it might me very basic, but how do I run this code in PHP?

I tried:

```
mysql_query('SET @i = 0;
UPDATE albums SET id=(@i:=@i+1);');
```

but that doesn't do anything

Thanks for the advice!
best Sam

Comment: Why don't you simply have an autoincrement id column?

Comment: I need a consecutive list in order to give each entree a number. auto_increment always picks up where it left, not considering deleted entrees ..

Comment: Why do you __need__ a consecutive number? It shouldn't be necessary for a PK to be consecutive, simply unique, otherwise it's not being used purely as a PK

Comment: The order of the IDs is arbitrary? And you regenerate the complete table every time you insert or delete a row, possibly changing existing IDs? What's the the use case for that feature?

Comment: I want to 'attach' a number to each album I create, and display that number. I can't do this in PHP, since the numbers should exist independent of SORT BY method, and a standard loop will base it's sequence on the result after it's sorted.
indeed, after an album is added or deleted I will update the ID column. If this is real strange, I'd be curious to hear the proper alternative ..  thx

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_query()` sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported),So that your code not works.You can try it with different `mysql_query()`.

```
mysql_query('SET @i = 0');
mysql_query('UPDATE albums SET id=(@i:=@i+1)');
```

Answer (score 1):

Since mysql_query() is deprecated in PHP 5.5.0 and mysqli_query() not support multiple queries, the best answer is:

```
mysqli_multi_query('set @i = 0; update albums set id = (@i:=@i+1);');
```

Comment: Now i will start using mysqli_multi_query(),thanks  +1

Answer (score 0):

How about using single update query with join

```
mysql_query("update albums 
join(SELECT @i:=0) t
SET id=(@i:=@i+1)");
```

But its better if you can change schema of your table then make id [*AUTO_INCREMENT*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

[*demo for update join query*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25814/1)